# Try to Implement MSAA on DX12, but There's Format Error

Tags: c++, directx-12, msaa

I Modified every PSO's SampleDescs, Render Target's sampleCount and sampleQuality but there's D3D12 error.

it says

D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateGraphicsPipelineState: The specified sample count or quality is not supported with the render target format in slot 0 [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #685: CREATEGRAPHICSPIPELINESTATE_INVALID_SAMPLE_DESC]

D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateGraphicsPipelineState: The specified sample count or quality is not supported with the render target format in slot 1 [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #685: CREATEGRAPHICSPIPELINESTATE_INVALID_SAMPLE_DESC]

D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateGraphicsPipelineState: The specified sample count or quality is not supported with the specified depth-stencil format [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #685: CREATEGRAPHICSPIPELINESTATE_INVALID_SAMPLE_DESC]

Down below is codes.

CreateTexture2DResource function's last two parameter is sampleCount and sampleQuality.

```
ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> CreateTexture2DResource(
ID3D12Device* device,
UINT width, UINT height, UINT elements, UINT miplevels, 
DXGI_FORMAT format, D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAGS resourceFlags, 
D3D12_RESOURCE_STATES resourceStates, D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE* clearValue, UINT sampleCount, UINT sampleQuality)
{
    ComPtr<ID3D12Resource> textureResource;

    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateCommittedResource(
    &Extension::HeapProperties(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
    D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
    &Extension::BufferResourceDesc(
        D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D,
        width, height, elements, miplevels,
        format, D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNKNOWN, resourceFlags, sampleCount, sampleQuality),
    resourceStates, clearValue, IID_PPV_ARGS(&textureResource)));

    return textureResource;
}

void InGameScene::CreateMsaaViews()
{
    D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE clearValue = { DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f} };

    mMsaaTarget = CreateTexture2DResource(
        mDevice.Get(), gFrameWidth, gFrameHeight, 1, 1,
        DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_RENDER_TARGET,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET, &clearValue, 4, mMsaa4xQualityLevels);

    D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle = mMsaaRtvDescriptorHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();

    mDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(mMsaaTarget.Get(), nullptr, rtvHandle);
    mMsaaRtvHandle = rtvHandle;
}

void InGameScene::CreateVelocityMapViews()
{
    D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE clearValue = { DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f} };

    mVelocityMap = CreateTexture2DResource(
        mDevice.Get(), gFrameWidth, gFrameHeight, 1, 1,
        DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_RENDER_TARGET,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET, &clearValue, 4, mMsaa4xQualityLevels);

    D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle = mVelocityMapRtvDescriptorHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();

    mDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(mVelocityMap.Get(), nullptr, rtvHandle);
    mVelocityMapRtvHandle = rtvHandle;

    D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc = {};
    srvDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
    srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.ResourceMinLODClamp = 0.0f;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.PlaneSlice = 0;

    D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE srvHandle = mVelocityMapSrvDescriptorHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
    mDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(mVelocityMap.Get(), &srvDesc, srvHandle);
    mVelocityMapSrvHandle = srvHandle;
}


void D3DFramework::CreateDepthStencilView()
{


D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC resourceDesc;
    resourceDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    resourceDesc.Alignment = 0;
    resourceDesc.Width = gFrameWidth;
    resourceDesc.Height = gFrameHeight;
    resourceDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
    resourceDesc.MipLevels = 1;

    resourceDesc.Format = mDepthStencilBufferFormat;
    resourceDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    resourceDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    resourceDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNKNOWN;
    resourceDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_DEPTH_STENCIL;

    D3D12_CLEAR_VALUE clearValue;
    clearValue.Format = mDepthStencilBufferFormat;
    clearValue.DepthStencil.Depth = 1.0f;
    clearValue.DepthStencil.Stencil = 0;

    D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapProperties = Extension::HeapProperties(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    ThrowIfFailed(mD3dDevice->CreateCommittedResource(
        &heapProperties,
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &resourceDesc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_DEPTH_WRITE,
        &clearValue,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&mDepthStencilBuffer)));

    D3D12_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilDesc = {};
    depthStencilDesc.Format = mDepthStencilBufferFormat;
    depthStencilDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
    depthStencilDesc.Flags = D3D12_DSV_FLAG_NONE;
    
    mD3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(
        mDepthStencilBuffer.Get(),
        &depthStencilDesc,
        DepthStencilView());
}
```

and also I modify PSO's Rasterizer Descriptor and Sample Descriptor like this :

```
mRasterizerDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = mMsaaEnable;
psoDesc.RasterizerState = mRasterizerDesc;

psoDesc.SampleDesc.Count = mMsaaEnable ? 4 : 1;
psoDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = mMsaaEnable ? mMsaa4xQualityLevels : 0;

psoDesc.BlendState = mBlendDesc;
psoDesc.DepthStencilState = mDepthStencilDesc;
psoDesc.SampleMask = UINT_MAX;
psoDesc.PrimitiveTopologyType = mPrimitive;
psoDesc.NumRenderTargets = 2;
psoDesc.RTVFormats[0] = mBackBufferFormat;
psoDesc.RTVFormats[1] = mVelocityMapFormat;
psoDesc.DSVFormat = mDepthStencilFormat;
```

in this code, Formats are

```
DXGI_FORMAT mBackBufferFormat   = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
DXGI_FORMAT mDepthStencilFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
DXGI_FORMAT mVelocityMapFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
```

I can't find anything wrong about this.

Is it possible that the multiple renderer target is the problem?

Comment: `Quality` has exactly two valid values:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_standard_multisample_quality_levels

Comment: it seems for dx11, I can't find similar macro for dx12.

Comment: Take a look at `DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC`

Comment: Have you reviewed the tutorial links I referred you to in your previous post?

Comment: yes, and I find where's wrong. sampleDesc.Quality must be mMsaa4xQualityLevels - 1.

Comment: Good work @Hansole_Jeong. I remember being caught by the _QualityLevels - 1_ rule for **SampleDesc.Quality** in my own project. You should post this as the answer.